# Android Studio Cannot Import Modules after upgrade

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I've just upgraded Android Studio to 0.2.11 but now i can no longer import modules (such as how the Facebook SDK is supposed to be imported

[image: Messed Up Project Structure]

I'm pretty sure when i click on Project Structure it should be more like this (with project settings on the left)

[image: Correct Project Structure]

Comment: For getting the Facebook SDK imported, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961828/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using gradle 1.8. In your screenshot, looks like you're using 1.6.

> Importing a project using the Android Gradle plug-in 0.6.1 and Gradle 1.6 or 1.7 will show the error: "Cannot create directory .idea". The real cause of the project import failure is that this version of the Android Gradle plug-in only supports Gradle 1.8 or later.

From http://tools.android.com/knownissues

Comment: This is when you're importing a project, not when you want to add a module to a project. In Android Studio, Gradle 1.7 and 1.8 have the same 'project structure' screen.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. A workaround is to select the project, right click -> 'Open module settings' (or just press F4). To import a module just press the '+' sign on top. To add dependecies (like a module), select the 'dependecies' tab and press the '+' sign on the right.