# Import module to gradle project on android studio 0.4.0v

Tags: android, android-studio, library-project

I need to import a library project as a module to an existing project.

Please Note!

There are answers to questions like that,

All answers regarding older versions of Android-Studio.

In older versions you could follow these steps:

- Open a project in Eclipse. (not exported him to gradle)
- In Android-Studio import this project as it.
- And than you have the File-->import module Option.

But in this version, when you try to import an Eclipse project,

The android studio convert it to gradle project anyway.

And then it's just like you open a new project in Android-Studio,

You don't have the File-->import module in the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing modules works correctly in Android Studio 0.5.5

Answer (score 6):

Importing modules isn't implemented yet for Gradle-based Android Studio projects. Bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62122 has been filed to track the progress of this. In the meantime, you have to bring in modules by hand; [using facebook sdk in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961828/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-studio/20221453#20221453) has detailed instructions.