# Using Facebook SDK in Android Studio 0.4.2

Tags: android-studio, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to create a new Android application that uses the Facebook SDK, I'm using latests versions for everything, so I'm using Android Studio 0.4.0 with the new Gradle compilation system and the latests version of the SDK downloaded from Facebook.

I have tried to follow the instructions in the Facebook Developers page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android-using-android-studio/3.0/
with no luck, because the instructions are not for a Gradle based Android Studio.

I have also tried to follow the instructions from Scott Barta in [using facebook sdk in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961828/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-studio/20221453#20221453) but no luck, the step 7 when "Sync Project with Gradle Files" is not working, I'm getting this error:

Failed to refresh Gradle project. You are using an old, unsupported version of Gradle. Please use version 1.9 or greater. Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.)

I have tried to modify the build.gradle file and change the classpath line from:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
```

to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
```

And also change the compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to the values I have in my project, but is not working.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

EDIT: I have updated today to Android 0.4.2 but no luck with the new version.

My gradle-wrapper.properties file is using Gradle 1.9:

```
#Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
 distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip
```

This is the build.gradle file I use to compile the Facebook library:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the complete build.gradle I use for my application:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile project(':libraries:facebook')
}
```

Now, when I click on Sync Project with Gradle Files I get the following error:

```
Gradle 'Testing' project refresh failed:
Project with path ':libraries:facebook' could not be found in project ':app'.
```

I have tried to change the path using: "libraries:facebook", "app:libraries:facebook", ":app:libraries:facebook"... but I'm always having the same error.

EDIT WITH SOLUTION:

With Android 0.4.2 and latest version of the Facebook SDK is really easy, Facebook SDK is including a build.gradle file that works, just only follow these steps:

- Create a folder called **"libs" (important, don't use other name!!! If you use "lib" may not work)**, at the **top** of your project (**important too, don't create in a subfolder!!!**).
- Copy the facebook folder from the downloaded SDK into the libs folder you just created.
- Include this line at the top of your settings.gradle:

  include ':libs:facebook'
- Include this line at the bottom of your build.gradle file, in the dependencies group:

  compile project(':libs:facebook')

Just click on "Sync Project with Gradle files", rebuild project and it should work!

EDIT FOR ANDROID STUDIO > 0.5.2:

Well, from Android Studio version 0.5.2, when a new project is created, a "libs" folder is created inside your project, so I think is a better idea to use that folder, so these are the steps:

- Copy the facebook folder from the downloaded SDK into the libs folder: YourProjectName/yourProjectName/libs
- Include this line at the top of your settings.gradle:

  include ':libs:facebook'
- Include this line at the bottom of your build.gradle file, in the dependencies group:

  compile project(':yourProjectName:libs:facebook')

Just click on "Sync Project with Gradle files", rebuild project and it should work!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add to the other answer, add the line 
`include ':libraries:facebook'` to your settings.gradle and you'll get a new error

```
Gradle 'Android' project refresh failed: Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

But hey this is what we call progress.

EDI:

Okay now it's working, here is exactly what I did.
- I put the FB SDK at the wrong path since the beginning, I was creating a libraries folder at the same level as my app, you should not, it'll not works. 
- Since Android Studio 0.4.+ the folder name should be libs and not libraries

Create a folder **libs** at the root of your project (same place where you find the settings.gradle)

Copy the Facebook folder from the Facebook SDK in the **libs** folder

In your `settings.gradle` add `include ':libs:Facebook'` before the include of your main app

In your build.gradle of your main app add this line in your dependencies

```
compile project(':libs:facebook')
```

Be sure that Android Support V4 is also one of your dependencies i.e:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
```

Also here is the build.gradle of my Facebook libs

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

Now sync gradle and everything should works fine, I'm on Android Studio 0.4.2 + Facebook SDK 3.6.0

Comment: There is a typo: `include ':libs:Facebook'` should be `include ':libs:facebook'`. SO won't let me edit it because that's only a single char.

Comment: it's possible to include Facebook SDK as Gradle-dependency, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23746667/1891118

Answer (score 1):

Use v0.7.+ of the Gradle plugin, as you've already done, and you want to make sure you're using v1.9 of Gradle (not 1.10, which is incompatible). If your project is using the Gradle wrapper (which is what I'd recommend), you can check the Gradle version which is embedded in the `distributionUrl` parameter in the gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file.

If you upgrade to Android Studio 0.4.2 it should check versions when you open the project and tell you how to correct problems if they exist.

**EDIT**

To fix your problem with

```
Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'include()'!
```

you need to correct your dependencies. To include another module as a dependency, use this:

```
compile project(':libraries:facebook')
```

If you go through the Project Structure dialog instead of editing the **build.gradle** files by hand, it can do it properly for you (though it won't fix the incorrect statement that uses `include`).

Comment: First of all, many thanks for your help.

This is my gradle-wrapper.properties file:

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip

Seems that I'm using Gradle 1.9.

And in build.gradle, I'm using 0.7.+:

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}

And I'm having the same error :(

Comment: Please update your question and add the details on your build files there. It's too difficult to read in a comment since all the formatting is lost.

Comment: Thanks again, I have updated my main question, I'm getting other different error :(

Comment: And I have tried to use the Project Structure dialog, but I can't add the facebook library, is like is not recognized as a library.