# Adding the pebblekit library to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I'm pretty new to Android Studio so I don't really know how to add a library (not a jar file, just a normal directory) to my android project. More exactly it's the pebblekit library I'm trying to add.

I've been trying to do this myself for a good while now and searching around internet w/o any good results. I'm using 0.4.2 of Android Studio.

Maybe someone can tell me what to do?

Comment: For integrating plain source directories as libraries, this answer relates how to do it with the Facebook library but the procedure should be almost the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961828/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-studio/20221453#20221453

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out based off of [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961828/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-studio/20221453#20221453)

1. Import the Android PebbleKit project from the pebble sdk into Android Studio.
2. Close the imported project and open the one you were working on.
3. Create a libraries folder in your project
4. Copy the directory for the imported PebbleKit into the libraries folder and rename it to PebbleKit
5. Add `include ':libraries:PebbleKit'` to yout settings.gradle file.|
6. Open your module settings for your application
7. Under add a module dependency for the libraries:PebbleKit