# Android Bootstrap implementation in Android Studio (Gradle)

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, android-bootstrap

i would like to implement Android Bootstrap http://androidbootstrap.com/ in Android studio.

On http://alpha.androidbootstrap.com/ is possibility to create prepared project for app, but i don't know, how exactly i should to add library into my project in Android Studio?

Could somebody give a step-by-step advice to me?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961828/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-studio/20221453#20221453 has instructions for introducing the Facebook library as a module; you should be able to adapt it for Android Studio.

Comment: I check that, but if i tried to sync project with Gradle i got a error message:
Gradle 'MyProject_Android' project refresh failed:Main Manifest missing from {absolute path to app}

Comment: Revise your question to show the state it's currently in, and add your build.gradle files.