# Removing facebook library Android Studio

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

I have followed this instruction to make use of the facebook sdk:
[using facebook sdk in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961828/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-studio)
but now I don't want to use the sdk anymore. I have removed the entire facebook map from the libraries map. And I removed everything what said "facebook". But still there is a folder in the libraries folder with a file that is called libraries.iml that is coming back when I start Android Studio or while it is active. Could someone explain me how I could get the facebook folder away? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hitting some known bugs in deleting modules: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61528 https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64720 (this is most closely related to what you're seeing even though the description seems quite different) and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61529

They'll be fixed for 0.4.5, and possibly 0.4.4, depending on how things go.

Sorry about the bugs, I know it's kind of a pain.

In the meantime, I'd suggest the following:

1. Exit Android Studio
2. Back up your project directory
3. Make sure the offending library's directory is deleted in the filesystem, and that it's gone from **settings.gradle**
4. Delete all your **.iml** files, and delete the **.idea** folder from the root of your project
5. Re-launch Android Studio and re-import your project