# issue importing maven project - android studio

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio

I am trying to import a project in `Android Studio` and I am very new to this `ide`. So, I created some `Libraries` folder, copied inside the file and then added one line (the last one) to to my `build.gradle` :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile ":libraries:library"
}
```

Edit :

I added some `settings.gradle` file with `include ":libraries:library"`

When I launch the `gradle` build I get

```
    A problem occurred configuring root project 'NewsFeeder'.
Total time: 6.507 secs
> Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

Here's a screen of my tree. Is the problem related to the `pom.xml` file inside the `IconicDroid-master` plugin

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that you need to have a **settings.gradle** file that tells Gradle where to find the library; it's not enough to put a path spec in your **build.gradle** file. However, I would recommend refactoring your project into a multimodule structure:

```
ProjectFolder
   +- NewsFeeder
   |  +-src
   |  +-res
   |  +-build.gradle
   +- iconicDroid-master
   |  +-src
   |  +-build.gradle
   +-settings.gradle
   +-build.gradle
```

Your **settings.gradle** file will look like this:

```
include ':NewsFeeder'
include ':iconicDroid-master'
```

You will need to set up a Gradle build file for your **iconicDroid** library; I wouldn't recommend trying to mix Gradle and Maven builders in the same project.

After you modify **build.gradle** or **settings.gradle** files, click the **Sync Project with Gradle Files** button in the toolbar to make the IDE pick up the changes.

To see a different example of integrating a library project with Android Studio, see [using facebook sdk in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961828/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-studio/20221453#20221453)

Comment: thank you for the response. I added some settings.gradle file and changed the tree as well. But now it is throwing another error (see my update). Btw, what am I supposed to do with the `pom` file in the `library` folder ?

Comment: You need to set up a build.gradle file for your library; it can't invoke Maven to build it. Maybe it's possible to call out to Maven from Gradle, but you'd be better off trying to set up a Gradle build for it -- it will be a lot less complicated.

Comment: Thank you again but how can you explain the message I get `A problem occurred configuring root project 'NewsFeeder'.
Total time: 6.507 secs
> Configuration with name 'default' not found.` Are my new settings in `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle` incorrect ?

Comment: The message isn't very helpful, but is what you see from Gradle when there are major problems with your build.gradle file, in this case, the nonexistence of it. I don't think this message is intentional; it's just how it happens to work.

Comment: @user1611830 error "'default' not found" comes when any module inside your project lying without its build.gradle file. So check and make them.