# Importing Facebook library in Android Studio: Could not find property 'ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, pagerslidingtabstrip

I want to import a library project into my app but whenever I try to do so , Android Studio doesn't recognise it

It also gives me errors in build.gradle ..

The Library is : PagerSlidingTabStrip ....

Here are some pictures :

> [image]
>
> [image]

I have been trying to make it work for 3 days so far !!
Please Help Me :)

***EDIT:***

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
    }
}
}

 apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

***EDIT2 :***

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':Sahertoday'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':Sahertoday:_debugCompile'.
> Could not find com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1.
 Required by:
     Saher-3:Sahertoday:unspecified

* Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get         more log output.

 BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Please post your build.gradle file. How did you declare that library ?

Comment: This is build.gradle for the library ..

Answer (score 54, accepted):

First of all, you can add this dependency to your project, without compiling the lib locally.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
}
```

Otherwise if you would like to compile this lib locally, you have to define these keys in gradle.properties in the root.

```
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=19
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=19
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=19
```

Comment: When I use the first step, error shows up (I post the error above) .. second step did not work as well !

Comment: With first solution, you should add repositories {
    mavenCentral()
} in your proj/build.gradle.

Comment: Execution failed for task ':Sahertoday:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merging failed. See console for more info.   Now this showed up :(   I really appreciate your help..

Comment: Thank you very much ,, I found the problem with the manifest .. Thanks Thanks :) Best Luck :)

Comment: This does not work for me. It still says it can't find the properties.

Comment: This is missing one other property. You also need to set: ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=19

Comment: How come the file "gradle.properties" doesn't exist for me by default?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I don't know. But you can create it.

Answer (score 38):

**EDIT**

There is also a GUI way for doing this. It is accessed by selecting the module `facebook` in the project tree and pressing `f4`. 
Also you can just right-click the `facebook` and go to `Open Module Settings` near the bottom. 
It is shown in the pictures. The numbers in the picture are top sdk version at the time of writing.

[image: first block - The numbers in the pictures don't match the above ones, but that's because I updated them later on.]

[image: second block - same update]

There is a simpler solution.
The constants like `ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION` can be replaced with normal version "numbers". So instead of

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 8
         targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
    }
```

..file can look like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 15
         targetSdkVersion 19
    }
```

Comment: In new version of Android Studio > 4.3 there is no module import option

Comment: @Xjet I am using version 0.8.9 and there is still option for module import. I find it under File->Import Module, right at the top. It seems yout have your versions mixed up.

Answer (score 3):

Go the facebook folder which you have imported in your project. Copy the gradle.properties file and paste in into your facebook module.It will remove the errors.

Answer (score 1):

For those who ran into same problems while adding libraries and still can't get it work. The following local include of the .aar file worked for me:

- Just download the .aar file from the [maven repo](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/com/astuetz/pagerslidingtabstrip/1.0.1/) manually.
- In Android Studio go to File -> new Module -> import .JAR or
  .AAR package and select your downloaded .aar file.

Android Studio does the rest (in the build.gradle) for you. Maybe clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 1):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 4
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```