# Unable to add dependency in Android Studio

Tags: android, dependencies, android-studio

I have been trying to add PagerSlidingTabStrip dependency to my project in  Android Studio and each time I get the following error:

`Error:Failed to find: com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1
 Open File
 Open in Project Structure dialog`

I tried to add the compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1' to build.gradle file but gradle sync returned the above stated error. And again the same error was generated when I tried to add dependency by going to Project Structure -> Dependencies -> Clicking + -> Searching for pagerslidingtab and added it from there.

I don't know how to get past through this.

[EDIT] I am using Android Studio 0.8.1 (beta)

Comment: please post your build.gradle file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the methods that I came across worked for me perfectly. However, in order to get the things done and move on with the project, I worked out the following:

Instead of adding dependency, module, I decided to include the java files individually into my project. Src files of Pager library going in src folder of my project, so on and so forth.

This worked out pretty well with the library I am using however this may not be the case with more complex libraries. And to be very frank, although this worked out for me but I'd still like to use the add via repository route.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question is asked here
[Importing Facebook library in Android Studio: Could not find property 'ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477884/importing-facebook-library-in-android-studio-could-not-find-property-android-b)
Just check whether this help you.
I am facing these kind of issues with Android Studio whenever it has some update. If you stuck with gradle, just try maven & see whether you are able to include the library & compile it properly.

Comment: The solution given there didn't work out for me. However I have found another work around using module - [link]https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio
I'll try the Method 2 given there and see if it ends my misery.

Comment: Nah. The above solution didn't work out for me. Any other solution?