# get ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION in other gradle file

Tags: java, android, facebook, gradle

In my Facebook library I has this

```
android {
compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
    targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
}
```

But then I get error it can't find `ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION` how can I get the ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION from the app.gradle file? So that when it is updated there it will also update in the Facebook library?

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Probably [this][1] will solve your problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21490651/3560534

Comment: @GiacomoDeBacco yes but then I need to change them there eveytime is there a way to getting values set in the app.gradle