# Facebook SDK in Android Studios not working?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, android-studio

Trying to import Facebook `SDK` into Android Studios, getting the following error:

```
 Error:(8, 0) Could not find property 'ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION' on project ':FriendPickerSample'.
```

I tried importing the modules as follows: **`File > Import Module > Facebook unzipped path.`**

I'm new to Android Studios and it's my first time trying to import any SDK, and I don't even know what 
`'FriendPickerSample'` is (I've tried searching around internet!).

Can someone please help me? What am I doing wrong, how can I solve this error?

**UPDATE**: I've tried adding BUILD_SDK_VERSION=20 (my sdk version is actually 20), still doesn't solve the error:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477884/importing-facebook-library-in-android-studio-could-not-find-property-android-b Check this link

Answer (score 0):

you define property ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION in you gradle.property.

```
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=(*Version)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't locate gradle.property in the facebook folder. Do you mean build.gradle? Also should the ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=(*VERSION) be the version of your Android SDK? Which in my case would be 19.

Comment: yes, try add ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=19 in proj/build.gradle

Comment: I found same issue is solved :D [Importing Facebook library in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477884/importing-facebook-library-in-android-studio-could-not-find-property-android-b)

Comment: I've tried adding it, doesn't work (see the screen shot in the question update)

Comment: Hey guys, the error 8 'could not find property on ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION' is on project 'FriendPickerSample',  so I tried to define the property i.e. =(*version '20') in build.gradle UNDER FriendPickerSample FOLDER...still no luck! Any suggestions?

Comment: Still getting the Error:(8, 0) Could not find property 'ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION' on project ':FriendPickerSample'. Any help?