# how to import library project in android studio

Tags: android, project

How to process to import the library project in Android studio

Comment: what library do you want to import?

Comment: we want to import googleplay service and facebook lib project on android studio

Answer (score 0):

You can import Google Play Services like this:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    }
```

found in https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

and Facebook SDK for Android like this:

like this:

```
dependencies { 
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
}
```

found in: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

i have done this task by
(1)firstly File -> New -> Import Module
(2)right click on your project -> select dependency tab -> click on + sign on right top corner -> then click on module dependency and select project 
for more you can see at
[Importing Facebook library in Android Studio: Could not find property 'ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477884/importing-facebook-library-in-android-studio-could-not-find-property-android-b)