# Importing Facebook SDK 3.0.2 on Android Studio 0.5.4

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

It's been quite some time I have been using stackoverflow for all my issues and I thought the day I'll have to post my own question would never come.

**So thank you StackOverflow community for all the help so far !!!**

I'm afraid that day has finally come, sot let's get to the point, shall we ?

I've been looking through the [Facebook guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android-using-android-studio/3.0/), and these StackOverflow questions with no luck at all:

" [using facebook sdk in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961828/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-studio) " ;

" [Import Facebook SDK on Android Studio 0.5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382905/import-facebook-sdk-on-android-studio-0-5-1) "

As explained in my title, I'm using the most recent versions of both the Facebook SDK which is `3.0.2` and Android Studio which is : `0.5.4`.

I really like and hate Android Studio at the same time. It offers incredible confort for developping on Android, but sometimes it can be a real nightmare as to how include libraries, modules and when you get IDE fatal internal errors ...

Anyway, to help you help me, here is the content of my project `settings.gradle` :

`include ':main', ':libs:facebook'`

### This is the content of my project' `build.gradle` :

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

     defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.darwinsys:hirondelle-date4j:1.5.1@jar'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':libs:facebook');
}
```

### Finally this is the content of `libs/facebook/build.gradle` :

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

And because answers can't be vague, this is the source tree of the facebook folder I extracted from the SDK downloaded archive :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEWa3.png

Well, this is it.
When I try to sync with Gradle, this is the error I am getting :

```
Gradle 'Travel3' project refresh failed:
Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

Please, do tell me where I am wrong save me from despair ! ^^

Comment: In a general sense that "Configuration with name 'default' not found" error means that something is usually misconfigured in your settings.gradle file, and it's pointing to a module that doesn't exist or it can't find for some reason -- usually because there's no build.gradle file where it's looking, or there's a serious problems with it that's keeping it from being parsed. In your case, it should be looking in the "main" directory off your project root, and also at "libs/facebook". If that's not enough of a hint to get you going, please post more details about your project's structure.

Comment: @ScottBarta you pointed me to right direction : it could not find the Facebook SDK build.gradle file because I wrongly included the lib in my **settings.gradle**. You may find details in my answer ! I hope this will help people in my exact situation !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution !

I took a lot of time to undestand how `settings.gradle` works.
I wrongly included the Facebook SDK as a lib ... so this is how it works -->

`include ':main', ':main:libs:facebook'`

As for the the rest is the same as in my original post.

So yeah, just because I forgot to add `:main:` ...