# Android Studio 0.6.0 Facebook SDK Import

Tags: android, facebook, gradle

I followed [using facebook sdk in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961828/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-studio) and since I have a libs folder under my 'app' folder, I tried to import it in there by selecting libs and File-->Import Module.  I get this:

[image: Android Studio 0.6.0 with Facebook SDK 3.14.1]

I'm able to run ProfilePictureSample, which relies on the facebook module, but not app.  Logcat says " java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.Facebook" even though I can verify it's there.  I get this messsage even after cutting the facebook module and pasting it into the libs folder.  Here is a snippet of app-->build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile files('libs/Parse-1.5.0/Parse-1.5.0.jar') ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't add it under the libs folder, it can be at the same level as "app".  In app/build.gradle, add this line:  "compile project(':facebook')"

Comment: It seems you do so due to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=71098?