# Android Studio 0.6.1 & Facebook SDK 3.15.0 famous error. how solve?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, android-studio

I'm trying to import Facebook SDK 3.15.0 to Android Studio 0.6.1.
I do follow Rani's explanation on [using facebook sdk in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961828/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-studio) both for Android Studio earlier than 0.5.5 & the later one.

The error I get says something like this.

**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Error: A library uses the same package as this project: liquidcode.se.facebooktest
>   You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
>   However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0**

I also did include it in the setting.gradle & imported as module for the app.

I read now that many have the same problem, but how to fix it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the ApplicationId from your facebook sdk library build.gradle file.
It should end up looking something like this.

//Wrong

```
      defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bz.buktest"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
       }
```

//Right

```
     defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 10
         targetSdkVersion 19
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
}
```

Done. Your problem should be solved. Hope you got it.

Answer (score 0):

I would start over, and add the project via the `File -> Project Structure` dialog. Mine worked with minimal additional effort after adding the sdk via the Project Structure dialog.

After adding via the `Project Structure` dialog, you need to change `buildToolsVersion` in Facebook's `build.gradle` file.

Also delete the component named `FacetManager` in Facebooks .iml file.

If you follow those three steps you should have Facebook's sdk properly integrated into your project.

Comment: I did what you wrote with your three steps but the first one didnt work.

1. File -> Import Module (the path to the facebook folder).
2. File -> Project Structure (import the module).
3. Open up the Facebook build.gradle change the builtToolsVersion and so on.
4. I even tried to delete the FacetManager from the component in Facebooks.iml file, but still, same error, so your steps didnt work.

Comment: Your path to the Facebook folder should be the inner folder labeled "facebook" within the "Facebook-android-sdk-XXX" folder. Make sure you linked to that folder. Additionally delete facet manager in the any and all .iml files within the project.

Comment: Yes, i know which Facebook folder I need to choose.
I see only facetManager in one place in the .iml file, but dont think thats the problem. I googled and saw that alot of other people do have the same problem. Do you use Android Studio 0.6.1 or earlier? Do you use Facebook-SDK-3.15.0 or earlier? Because that matters. 

The errormessage also said: android.enforceUniquePackageName=false. Where do I write that? With that written in the build.gradle, dont know where or which one, but that would help.