# Installing Facebook Sdk in Android Studio 1.0.2

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am trying to install Facebook SDK in Android Studio 1.0.2. However, i can not find any tutorial to tell how can i achieve this. Because 1.0.2 version of Android Studio is very different from the previous versions. How can i install Facebook SDK in Android Studio 1.0.2

Comment: possible duplicate of [using facebook sdk in android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961828/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, nothing complicated or new there, comparing to any previous verison of Android Studio.

1. Verify that you have repositories configured:

   repositories {
       jcenter()
   }
2. Add Facebook SDK:

   dependencies {
       compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.22.0'
   }
3. Refresh Gradle project.