# failed to find:com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 1.0.1 and trying to integrate Facebook to my application. I followed this tutorial and followed each step- [using facebook sdk in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961828/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-studio).

I have downloaded **facebook-android-sdk-3.21.1** to integrate facebook. But I am getting

`failed to find:com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4` error. I didn't get any solution and completely fed-up with this. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: down voter..!! if u know the answer, then post it here and then down vote..!!

Comment: You should better use latest 4.0.1 FB SDK, cause I'm not sure, that old versions will work after [April 30](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog). Also you can find compiled library in [repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.parse.bolts/bolts-android).

Comment: Please note that a down vote on a question and answering the question are completely unrelated matters. And I agree with the down-vote, your question is missing key information to identify the issue (I would start by posting your build.gradle file)

Comment: @AnirudhSharma there is no need to add a comment, OP is notified of any new answer.

Answer (score 0):

The better way i found out for adding facebook sdk without any problems was

add this in your build.gradle

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1'
```

or by using the following method:-

1>right click on your project and open **module settings**

2>go to **Dependencies** and click the **plus button (Green One)**

3>click **library dependency**

4>search for **facebook** and you will find your sdk there,then simply add it

and still if you want to do the way you are currently doing then you may want to add the bolts jar as your dependency using `compile'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.2'` and do check for the version you want.

Comment: okk...I used your second method and followed all steps. After adding facebook, I got `Error:Failed to find: com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1`

Comment: @RuchirTarawat can you please paste your build.gradle