# Error in import Facebook SDK 4.1.2 in Android Studio 1.1.0

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

> C:\Users\PC\AndroidStudioProjects\FacebookSDK\facebook\build.gradle
>   Error:(15, 0) Could not find property 'ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION' on
>   project ':facebook'.

Comment: Please add some text to you answer to explain what you are doing or it will,  very likely, be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.2'` to your dependencies in the build.gradle file of your app!
EDIT: [image: Example]

Comment: Error:(112, 0) Cannot call getBootClasspath() before setTargetInfo() is called.

Comment: dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:[21,22)'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.2'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

Comment: Please tell me your Gradle Version. You can find it in the other build.gradle file. Right above the yellow marked!

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

Comment: Please try to change it to 1.2.3 and tell me if the Error still occurs.

Comment: Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 20.0.0
Install Build Tools 20.0.0 and sync project

Comment: Go into the Android SDK Manager and update the Android SDK Build-Tools

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':facebook:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\Android\NewAndroid\build-tools\22.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Did you already change the buildToolsVersion in your build.gradle file to the one you downloaded (hopefully the newest)?

Comment: i changed it and build faild

Comment: Could you please upload a picture of your gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

Write all those variables values in "gradle.properties" file.

Like

ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=21

ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=21.1.0

ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=21

ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=9

Comment: Error:(111, 0) Cannot call getBootClasspath() before setTargetInfo() is called.

Comment: go through this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961828/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-studio