# Import Facebook Android SDK (Android studio 1.2.2)

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

I am trying to add the Facebook Android SDK to my LibGdx project, however none of the solutions I find work for me.

Either people say to compile the SDK inside your Gradle.build modules, which does not work for me. Or they say that you shud go *File>Import Module>Import Facebook SDK*. But there is no "import module" in Android Studio 1.2.2.

Not sure why I can't get this to work, does anyone have any recent experience with getting Facebook Android SDK 4.4.1 working in Android Studio 1.2.2?

Comment: You have to explain your problem. What problem are you facing when you  follow this tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Answer (score 3):

It's in *File* > *New...* > *Import Module*. It'll ask you for the path to the module, set that to the *facebook* directory inside the Facebook sdk zip.

Check out this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20221453/2197700

Comment: Can you help me figure out why the current fb Android SDK is version 4.4.1, but when I import it in my gradle.build I have to use Version 4.1.0 or it cannot be resolved.

Comment: Maybe they haven't uploaded newer versions to the maven repository, and expect people to download it from their site?

Comment: Ya maybe, but then what is the point of giving an option to use anything but a local downloaded SDK if the one on maven is gonna be outdated. Ill just hope this works cus using the local SDK messed up my entire project

Comment: I'm guessing they're migrating to downloading the stuff? Did you figure it out? You need to add the module dependency by hitting F4 on your old module, going to dependencies.

Comment: Ya I figured it out, like I said I had to use version 4.1.0

Comment: Huh that's strange... At least you have it working :)