# Error Migrating Eclipse project to Android Studio causing Error Library reference (Facebook SDK) not found

Tags: android

I am getting this error when I am migrating my eclipse project to Android Studio
Error Migrating Eclipse project to Android Studio causing Error Library reference (Facebook SDK) not found. Can you guide me any way of migrating Eclipse Project. Please see below image link. I am getting this issue

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDlVR.png

Comment: Try This:--- https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html     http://www.developer.com/ws/android/migrating-from-eclipse-to-android-studio.html

Comment: i tried this but no luck it wont allow me to migrate it because linking facennok SDk reference issue. I have also copied the jar file and placed it in eclipse libs folder but no luck. when I import project, first it shows the the above mention image than this error Unrecovverable error which must be corrected first" and project not created

Answer (score 0):

You need to add facebook sdk manually.

you can follow this [using facebook sdk in android studio](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)

you check this also

[using facebook sdk in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961828/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-studio)

Comment: The whole project is completed in eClipse. now I am doing import (eclipse ADT project) in android studio. This giving me the error "Unrecovverable error which must be corrected first"and project is not created in android studio.