# Finish button disabled when importing Android Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, apk

Im trying to add a facebook login to my login screen. in order to do so, I imorted facebook andrdoid sdk to my project.

Followed the steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961828/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-studio) answer.

But, when I'm Importing, the project New module Window shows an error message called, "Specify Location of the gradile or Andrdoid Eclipse project" and the Finish button is disabled so that I cannot proceed to import the SDK.

See the image.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to import sdk you can add line in your build.gradle

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll check. :)