# How to add Facebook dependency in offline mode on Android Studio

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, import-module

I am trying to write a program that can make Facebook updates but i have issues adding the Facebook dependency. I already have the `sdk` but couldn't add to my project because... [image: Err]
even though i have tried adding the `gradle.prperties` file to the extracted Facebook folder as a comment suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961828/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-studio)

Next i tried adding as suggested on the [Facebook official page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) but i hit this snag...[image: Err2]

Now, because if the price of data where I'm from, I'd rather not go online since I already have the sdk locally so my question is **how can i manually cache the sdk into my project?**

EDIT: For clarity, my question is ***HOW DO I ADD THE FACEBOOK SDK INTO MY PROJECT WITHOUT GOING ONLINE (i.e. OFFLINE BUILD)?***

Comment: are you already solve this?

Comment: none of the answers worked.

Answer (score 3):

Download Facebook Android SDK 4.24.0 ARR it from [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/4.24.0/facebook-android-sdk-4.24.0.aar)

Then,
In order to import a .aar library:

1. Add a .aar file in **libs** folder.
2. Use "New Module" option under File menu.
3. Import the .aar file.
4. Build gradle and compile the project.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, all you need to do is set android studio's offline compile option and build it once. After that, you can re-build as much as you can without going online.

Here is a link on setting the offline option. Hope it helps: https://hackernoon.com/speed-up-gradle-build-in-android-studio-80a5f74ac9ed?gi=2bb71fe06274

Comment: this doesn't help me at all

Answer (score 1):

try this offline mode on Android Studio

[image: disable offline][image: enable offline]