# Android - ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, google-play-services, okhttp, android-facebook

I'm getting error like below for Lollipop devices..

```
com.hyperkonnect.happyemi.mock E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.hyperkonnect.happyemi.mock-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hyperkonnect.happyemi.mock-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk"

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.hyperkonnect.happyemi.mock-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hyperkonnect.happyemi.mock-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hyperkonnect.happyemi.mock-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk"
```

I tried the following changes but nothing worked.

- I change the Google Play Services Version.
- I tried to change Facebook SDK Version.
- I tried to disable the Instant Run.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done so, try to create and update your [Facebook Developer Settings](https://developers.facebook.com/settings/developer/sample-app/) with the key hashes for your development environments.

Also, you need to [generate and set a Release Key Hash](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash).

For more information, check this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started). Then for additional insights, you may want to also check these:

- [Embed Facebook SDK for Android in your Delphi mobile app (Part 2)](https://blog.grijjy.com/2017/01/30/embed-facebook-sdk-for-android-in-your-delphi-mobile-app-part-2/)
- [Using Facebook SDK in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20221453).

Comment: Thanks bro. I will let you know If it will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to **enable** (yes, enable) Instant Run to see if it works. My project runs into the same problem, only on Lollipop devices, and turning Instant Run on fixes for me.

To enable it:

- On Mac, click **Android Studio → Preferences**
- On Windows and Linux, **click File → Settings**

Then go to **Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run**, and check the box "Enable Instant Run...".